# Does the existence of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to + \infty } \frac{{f(x)}}{x}$ always imply the existence of asymptote?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

To compute the oblique asymptote as $x \to +\infty$, we can first compute $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{f(x)}}{x}$, it it exists, and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{f(x)}}{x} = k$, then we can further compute $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } (f(x) - kx)=b$, and if it exists then the asymptote would be $y = kx + b$.

But I am wondering if the existence of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{f(x)}}{x}$ always imply the existence of the second limit $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } f(x) - kx$ and hence the asymptote? If not, any counterexample is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't. Consider for example $f(x) := x + \sin(x)$. Then

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x + \sin(x)}{x} = 1 + \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1 $$

because $\sin$ is bounded. It is clear that $g(x) = x$ has an asymptote at infinity but by adding the bounded oscillating function $\sin x$ to $g$, it is clear that the resulting function $f$ won't have an asymptote at infinity (because it oscillates around $g(x) = x$ as $x$ approaches infinity). And indeed,

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) - x = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sin x $$

doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Generally no - just take any function $f(x)$ that grows sub-linearly at infinity. For example, $$ f(x) = \sqrt{x} $$ means $k=0$, but then $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) - kx) = \lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{x} = \infty. $$