# If $f$ is convex (or concave), does the existence of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to + \infty } \frac{{f(x)}}{x}$ imply the existence of asymptote?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis

A follow-up question for the [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184056/does-the-existence-of-mathop-lim-limits-x-to-infty-fracfxx) one.

> To compute the oblique asymptote as $x \to +\infty$, we can first compute $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{f(x)}}{x}$, if it exists, and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{f(x)}}{x} = k$, then we can further compute $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } (f(x) - kx)=b$, and if it exists then the asymptote would be $y = kx + b$.
>
> Now the existence of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{f(x)}}{x} = k$ does not in general imply existence of the second limit $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } (f(x) - kx)=b$, as a counterexample $f(x)=x+\sin x$ shown by [levap](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/32262/levap) in the previous question.

But **what if we restrict** $f$ being convex (or concave)? Will the claim hold in this case? The counterexample $f(x)=x+ \sin x$ now fails as it is neither convex or concave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others (user Michael, who for some reason did not believe in himself) noticed, there is the concave counterexample with $k=0$ $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \ln x&\text{if }x>1\\ x-1&\text{if }x\le1\end{cases}$$

And hence the convex counterexample $-f(x)$ with $k=0$. And $-f(x)+\alpha x$ for arbitrary $k$.

Comment: I was thinking when I re-read the question that the non-existence of $b$ meant it wasn't a counterexample.  A third reading shows it is :)